# How to remove duplicates function calls in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a good way to remove a set of function calls like below?

```
def set_area_vars
  @leftarea1 = hstore_string_to_hash(@webcast.leftarea1) if @webcast.leftarea1.present?
  @midarea1 = hstore_string_to_hash(@webcast.midarea1) if @webcast.midarea1.present?
  @leftarea2 = hstore_string_to_hash(@webcast.leftarea2) if @webcast.leftarea2.present?
  @midarea2 = hstore_string_to_hash(@webcast.midarea2) if @webcast.midarea2.present?
  @rightarea2 = hstore_string_to_hash(@webcast.rightarea2) if @webcast.rightarea2.present?

  @resource1 = webcast_area_convert_resources(@leftarea1) if @leftarea1
  @resource2 = webcast_area_convert_resources(@midarea1) if @midarea1
  @resource3 = webcast_area_convert_resources(@leftarea2) if @leftarea2
  @resource4 = webcast_area_convert_resources(@midarea2) if @midarea2
  @resource5 = webcast_area_convert_resources(@rightarea2) if @rightarea2
end
```

and below code:

```
  def sidebar_menu(top_level = ["Venues", "globe"], menu_class = "venue-nav", menu_items = [[venues_dashboard_path, "Dashboard"]], expanded = false)
    @sidebar_menu_item ||= []
    @menu_items ||= []
    add_sidebar_menu(top_level, menu_class, @menu_items.concat(menu_items), expanded)
    if user_signed_in?
      if current_user.has_role? :admin
        @hide_sidebar = 'hide-sidebar' if current_user.has_role? :visitor if user_signed_in?
          add_sidebar_menu ["Users", "users"], "user-nav", [[users_path, "List users"], [new_user_path, "Create a user"], [new_user_invitation_path, "Invite user"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'users'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Forums", "comments"], "forum-nav", [[forums_path(@venue), "List forums"], [new_forum_path(@venue), "Create a forum"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'forums'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Resources", "pencil"], "literature-nav", [[literatures_path(@venue), "List resources"], [new_literature_path(@venue), "Create a resources"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'literatures'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Partners", "user"], "partner-nav", [[partners_path(@venue), "List partner"], [new_partner_path(@venue), "Create a partner"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'partners'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Sponsors", "user"], "sponsors-nav", [[sponsors_path, "List sponsors"], [new_sponsor_path, "Create a sponsor"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'sponsors'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Presentations", "beer"], "presentation-nav", [[presentations_path(@venue), "List presentations"], [new_presentation_path(@venue), "Create a presentation"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'presentations'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Products", "gift"], "product-nav", [[products_path(@venue), "List products"], [new_product_path(@venue), "Create a product"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'products'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Videos", "video-camera"], "video-nav", [[videos_path, "List videos"], [new_video_path, "Create a video"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'videos'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Templates", "folder"], "templates-nav", [[templates_path(@venue), "List templates"], [new_template_path(@venue), "Create a template"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'templates'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Q&A Chats", "comments-o"], "moderated-chats-nav", [[moderated_chats_path(@venue), "List chats"], [new_moderated_chat_path(@venue), "Create a chat"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'moderated_chats'
      elsif current_user.has_role? :vendor
        add_sidebar_menu ["Forums", "comments"], "forum-nav", [[forums_path(@venue), "List forums"], [new_forum_path(@venue), "Create a forum"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'forums'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Resources", "pencil"], "literature-nav", [[literatures_path(@venue), "List resources"], [new_literature_path(@venue), "Create a resources"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'literatures'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Partners", "user"], "partner-nav", [[partners_path(@venue), "List partner"], [new_partner_path(@venue), "Create a partner"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'partners'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Sponsors", "user"], "sponsors-nav", [[sponsors_path(@venue), "List sponsors"], [new_sponsor_path(@venue), "Create a sponsor"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'sponsors'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Presentations", "beer"], "presentation-nav", [[presentations_path(@venue), "List presentations"], [new_presentation_path(@venue), "Create a presentation"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'presentations'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Products", "gift"], "product-nav", [[products_path(@venue), "List products"], [new_product_path(@venue), "Create a product"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'products'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Videos", "video-camera"], "video-nav", [[videos_path, "List videos"], [new_video_path, "Create a video"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'videos'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Templates", "folder"], "templates-nav", [[templates_path(@venue), "List templates"], [new_template_path(@venue), "Create a template"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'templates'
      elsif current_user.has_role? :booth_rep
          add_sidebar_menu ["Resources", "pencil"], "literature-nav", [[literatures_path(@venue), "List resources"], [new_literature_path(@venue), "Create a resources"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'literatures'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Partners", "user"], "partner-nav", [[partners_path(@venue), "List partner"], [new_partner_path(@venue), "Create a partner"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'partners'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Sponsors", "user"], "sponsors-nav", [[sponsors_path(@venue), "List sponsors"], [new_sponsor_path(@venue), "Create a sponsor"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'sponsors'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Presentations", "beer"], "presentation-nav", [[presentations_path(@venue), "List presentations"], [new_presentation_path(@venue), "Create a presentation"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'presentations'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Products", "gift"], "product-nav", [[products_path(@venue), "List products"], [new_product_path(@venue), "Create a product"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'products'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Videos", "video-camera"], "video-nav", [[videos_path, "List videos"], [new_video_path, "Create a video"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'videos'
      elsif current_user.has_role? :host
        add_sidebar_menu ["Resources", "pencil"], "literature-nav", [[literatures_path(@venue), "List resources"], [new_literature_path(@venue), "Create a resources"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'literatures'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Partners", "user"], "partner-nav", [[partners_path(@venue), "List partner"], [new_partner_path(@venue), "Create a partner"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'partners'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Sponsors", "user"], "sponsors-nav", [[sponsors_path(@venue), "List sponsors"], [new_sponsor_path(@venue), "Create a sponsor"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'sponsors'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Presentations", "beer"], "presentation-nav", [[presentations_path(@venue), "List presentations"], [new_presentation_path(@venue), "Create a presentation"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'presentations'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Products", "gift"], "product-nav", [[products_path(@venue), "List products"], [new_product_path(@venue), "Create a product"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'products'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Videos", "video-camera"], "video-nav", [[videos_path, "List videos"], [new_video_path, "Create a video"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'videos'
          add_sidebar_menu ["Webcasts - settings", "play-circle-o"], "webcast-nav2", [[hall_webcasts_path(@hall), "List webcasts"], [new_hall_webcast_path(@hall), "Create a webcast"]], false unless params[:controller] == 'webcasts'
      elsif current_user.has_role? :visitor
        add_sidebar_menu ["Users", "users"], "user-nav", [users_path, "List users"], false unless params[:controller] == 'users'
      end
    end
```

I was thinking of `meta programming` `send` method or `eval` method but then how would I look those objects as I still need to check with `present?` condition to see if the association even exists

Answer (score 0):

Wow. That's a lot of code. Unless I'm mistaken, in the second part there is some repetition from `Resources` to `Videos`. You could isolate that part to ie. a `default_menus` method.

In the first part there is the possibility of reducing repetition. You can eliminate the distinction between left/mid/right areas and resources and use an array instead. Then you would get something like:

```
def set_area_vars
  @resources = (0..4).map do |i|
    webcast_area_convert_resources(hstore_string_to_hash(@webcast.areas[i])) if @webcast.areas[i].present?
  end
end
```

This assumes that you have reassigned the left/mid/right areas to an array named `@webcast.areas` and that `@resources` is now also an array (zero based index). It's up to you to decide if that is worth the refactoring job.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest it would be technically possible to coax ruby metaprogramming into giving you almost anything, however it is doubtful your code will remain readable after such a refactoring. As @zwippie suggested this would be easier to do if you could convert your instance variables into arrays, but that will most likely involve changing your views too.

The first part of your code will be fairly easy to refactor as suggested by @zwippie, the second part should be refactored differently. I would suggest to have an array with all the sidebar_menu entries (e.g. as lambdas if you do not want to evaluate them all the time) and some kind of level (or a method which decides if the menu entry should display for a certain role). Then you can write a loop which operates on the menu entries and the role and returns a sidebar_menu which is appropriate for the role.